# Syntax Error on if statement Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fix the notification icon problem. Above android version 26 a specific type of icon, and below 26 another icon...
But I couldn't figure out how to solve this syntax error. By the way there is no problem in getting android.Build number. Firebase also logs it correctly.

Syntax error is in line: `if(sdknumber>26){`
Code is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification =functions.database.ref('/notifyList/{receiver_id}/{sdk_number}/{notification_id}')
    .onWrite((change,context) =>
{
        const receiver_id = context.params.receiver_id;
        const sdk_number = context.params.sdk_number;
        const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
        console.log('Notification to send: ',receiver_id);
        console.log('SDK Number: ',sdk_number);
        const sdknumber = Integer.parseInt(sdk_number);

        //const afterData = change.after.val();

        if(!change.after.exists()) 
        {
          return console.log('notification deleted from DB :',notification_id);
          return null;          
        }
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Messenger/userlist/${receiver_id}/tokenID`).once('value');

    return deviceToken.then(result =>
    {
       const token_id = result.val();
       const payload = 
       {
            if(sdknumber>26){
                notification:
                {
               title: "New message!",
               body: "Tab to read it!",
               sound: "default",
               click_action: "OPENNOTIFICATION",
               icon: "rateiconsari"               
                }                   
            }else{
                notification:
                {
               title: "New message!",
               body: "Tab to read it!",
               sound: "default",
               click_action: "OPENNOTIFICATION",
               icon: "logo2"                  
                }                       
            }

       };

       return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload)
                .then(response =>
                {
                    console.log('notification sent');
                });
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `payload` defines a literal JavaScript object You can't put an `if` statement inside an object declaration like that.

You can either use a `?:` operator:

```
const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: "New message!",
            body: "Tab to read it!",
            sound: "default",
            click_action: "OPENNOTIFICATION",
            icon: sdknumber > 26 ? "rateiconsari" : "logo2"
          }                   
   };
```

Or you can use an `if/else` outside of the definition to modify the `payload` based on the SDK version:

```
var payload =  {
         notification:{
           title: "New message!",
           body: "Tab to read it!",
           sound: "default",
           click_action: "OPENNOTIFICATION",
           icon: "rateiconsari"                                     
        }

   };
if(sdknumber <= 26) {
    payload.icon = "logo2";
}
```

Note that this is a pure JavaScript syntax problem, and has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: Thank you so much. First one has worked like charm! Also there was a problem with  " Integer.parseInt(sdk_number);" part no Integer needed... Just parseInt(...)...